# How to handle Web.*.config transform in Octopus Deploy when the config has duplicate keys

Tags: web-config, octopus-deploy, web-config-transform

In Octopus Deploy, I'm trying to have my Web.config be transformed using my Web.Debug.Config and I'm getting the following error:

> Found multiple target elements, but the 'Replace' Transform only applies to the first match

Notice that the two application settings sections contain a setting with the same name.

```
<applicationSettings>
<My.Namespace1>
  <setting name="FeatureFlag" serializeAs="String">
    <value>True</value>
  </setting>
</My.Namespace1>
<My.Namespace2>
  <setting name="FeatureFlag" serializeAs="String">
    <value>False</value>
  </setting>
</My.Namespace2>
</applicationSettings>
```

Here is the transform that Octopus Deploy is using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
<applicationSettings>
    <My.Namespace1>
        <setting name="FeatureFlag" serializeAs="String" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="Replace">
            <value>False</value>
        </setting>
    </My.Namespace1>
    <My.Namespace2>
        <setting name="FeatureFlag" serializeAs="String" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="Replace">
            <value>True</value>
        </setting>
    </My.Namespace2>
</applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: There are two nodes for `My.Namespace2` in the latter code block. I guess that is a mistake.

Comment: That was a mistake and has been changed. Thanks!